# update table in database with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i want to insert selected texts in my page in table with clicking on button in my page but my problem is it doenst insert . select text is correct i tested it.
response that i receive is my selected texts

This is my index page and i passed my texts into variable text

```
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var text = $("span:not([dir=rtl])").text();
            $("#btn").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url:'process.php',
                    data:{'text':text},
                    success:(function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
```

this is my process.php that connects to database and perform query but runs else statement

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sahifeDB";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = 'update sahife_tbl set english ='. $_POST['text'].' where id=1 ';
$result = $conn->query($conn,$sql);
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Does console show anything

Comment: Show what you got as response...

Comment: [Turn on your PHP error reporting.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438125/1022914)

Comment: You do NOT want to directly concatenate POST variables into your SQL. This makes you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - see here for how to better solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: What is the type of `english` field in your table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: @Mikey the type is text

Comment: @clearshot66 no

Comment: @sepher Then you need to use quotes as shown in the answers below. Or BETTER prepared statements :O

Comment: @sepehr Why are you also running the query twice? Remove `$conn->query($conn,$sql);`. I've never used mysqli but that doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `"` in update statement as datatype is text for field

change your query to:

```
$sql = 'update sahife_tbl set english ="'. $_POST['text'].'" where id=1 ';
```

Also use **Prepared statement** to prevent from sql injection

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around your string value in the query otherwise your DB will try to parse the text as part of the syntax and fall over.

```
$sql = "update sahife_tbl set english ='". $_POST['text']."' where id=1 ";
```

But again as mentioned in my comment on your question, this is super insecure, you want to use parameterisation instead - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/635522